# How to change linux file owner and run using crontab?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script with user ivr. How can I change the user ivr to root?

Currently it has:

```
        -rwx------ 1 ivr  ivr  543 Nov 22 16:46 db-backup.sh
```

I wanted like below:

```
        -rwx------ 1 root  root  700 Nov 22 16:46 db-backup.sh
```

and my script location is /usr/backup/mysql how can i run this file using crontab at every midnight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the ownership:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/backup/mysql/db-backup.sh
```

To run at midnight using crontab, run `sudo crontab -e`.  That will open a file in an editor. Add the following line to the bottom of the file and save the file:

```
0  0  * * *   /usr/backup/mysql/db-backup.sh
```

The script will now run at midnight every night.